# Sql multiple select into

Tags: sql, oracle, select-into

How can I set multiple `into` inside a select query in Oracle according to the following sql query.

```
declare
    v_a out varchar2;
    v_b out varchar2;
    v_c out varchar2;

    begin
        select a , b , c into v_a, v_b, v_c from table
    end
```

Comment: Apart from missing semicolons and variable sizes, that is what you do, for a single row of data; so what is your question? Do you want to know how to handle multiple rows being returned? What do you want to do with the data you get back?

Comment: What you have posted is correct if you get only one record from your table for the query 

More detail about your requerement will get you more help from SO...

Comment: If you want to do this for each row in the table then you may want to put it in a loop...

Comment: You may use the same parameter to the block of the procedure as well as the out parameter of the procedure. no need of multiple into.

Answer (score 2):

If your table contains single record then what you have given is correct, except the things mentioned by @AlexPoole in his comments. Also, you cannot use `OUT` in the annonymous block.

In case your table contains multiple records then you will need to create a collection to store records and do `BULK COLLECT` in your query. the pseudo code for that will be something like:

```
          Declare
               TYPE c_var is table of varchar2(100);
               v_a c_var ;
               v_b c_var ;
               v_c c_var ;

          Begin

                Select a, b, ,c BULK COLLECT INTO v_a, v_b, v_c from table;  
          END;
```

You can then loop through the collection to access the individual elements.

Hope it Helps

Vishad

Comment: thanks @vishad i tried again my query this time fired finely.I have been specified above but i forgot to put an out parameter.Excuse me.